# How to add a dropdown list to a Jhipster entity page that list all records from anther entity

Tags: angularjs, search, filter, jhipster

I have generated an instance of Jhipster, which has a person entity and a family-link entity.

In the person entity, I listed a bunch of people. In the family-link I want to link them together. i.e. Person A is a son of Person B, Person C is the wife of Person D etc.

On the family-link "Add new" page, I want to have a few dropdown lists with search function that lists all the people from Person Entity. Something link this:

- Name: John Doe
- Father: (Drop Down List of Person)
- Mother: (Drop Down List of Person)
- Child: (Drop Down List of Person)

I have tried to use code like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label translate="archerApp.familyLink.child" for="field_child">Child</label>
            <ui-select ng-model="vm.familyLink.child" id="field_child"  ng-disabled="disabled" >
                <ui-select-match placeholder="Select or search a person name in the list...">{{$select.selected.firstname + ' ' + $select.selected.lastname}}</ui-select-match>
                <ui-select-choices repeat="person in vm.people | filter: $select.search track by person.id"
                                   refresh="refreshPerson($select.search)" refresh-delay="0">
                    <span ng-bind-html="(person.firstname+' '+person.lastname) | highlight: $select.search"></span>
                </ui-select-choices>
            </ui-select>
        </div>
```

The problem is this code can only list the first 20 people from Person entity. I think I should use the ElasticSearch API and something like,

```
<form name="searchForm" class="form-inline">
                <div class="input-group pull-right" >
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.searchQuery" id="searchQuery" placeholder="{{ 'archerApp.person.home.search' | translate }}">
                    <span  class="input-group-btn width-min" >
                        <button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="vm.search(vm.searchQuery)">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                        </button>
                    </span>
                    <span class="input-group-btn width-min" ng-if="vm.currentSearch">
                        <button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="vm.clear()">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                        </button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </form>
```

This is the code for the search bar on the Person entity. But I don't know how to make it work with the job downlist.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your entities are probably paginated, which means that the requests to retrieve data include pagination variables (`size` and `page`) that specify how much data to retrieve. If these variables do not exist, then the server will use the default page size (I believe the default is `page: 0` and `size: 10` but that may have been changed). This happens in your angular controllers.

Example without pagination variables that will use the default page size:

```
vm.entities = Entity.query();
```

Example with pagination variables:

```
vm.entities = Entity.query({
    page: 0,
    size: 20
});
```

If you want your dropdowns to show more than 20 entities, then you need to set the page size to something higher.